# Why does "scanning disks" always take 3 -4 hours?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, system-installation

Is there something wrong with my hard drive?  I have tons of small files on my C drive in Windows.  I shrunk that partition to make enough room for a new partition.  It's taken me days just to get this far.

In GParted, the same thing, 3 - 4 hours just to get it to go from "searching disks" or whatever it is, to the next screen where it actually lets me do something.  Before I shrunk my partition, I had to defrag the hard drive and now my Windows 7 runs great, but I still wanted to install Ubuntu 13.10 on the 50 Gb or so I created for Linux.

I finally got to the point where I could put my installation live CD in and thought after one wait while "scanning disks" scanned my disks, I could install and be done with it - but I got an error "no root file defined" or something like that, so back to google I went to find out I had to type in `/` somewhere only to have the installation once again go back to "scanning disks".

Now come to find out it's recommended that I create a swap partition too, so I imagine I still have 2 or 3 more 3 - 4 hour wait periods to look forward to and if I make a mistake, it's even more.

In view of the fact that my Windows 7 installation runs great now, is there something wrong with my hard disk or is it the tons of small files on my C drive or is it something else that is causing all these excruciatingly long wait periods?

Comment: You have to create a `/` root partition and a `swap` partiton, you may also want a `/home` partiton to save your files in. The hard disk can take a long time to scan depending on its size & speed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Can this be done from the Ubuntu 13.10 installation CD or do I have to go back to gparted?

Comment: The Ubuntu 13.10 installer can do it automatically, or you can specify what you want in 'Something Else'.